# Hide 'add to cart' when certain value in dropdown is selected AND certain Vendor is selling

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, vendor

I am trying to hide the 'add to cart' woocommerce button when a user selects a specific item in a dropdown list AND a certain vendor is selling (E.g. Bob smith). I am using the WordPress platform and have a base query which works (see below). I just need assistance with including the specific vendor part please.

**In Functions.php theme file**

```
function load_scripts(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('select[name="select-1574795073993"]').on('change', function() {
                    if( this.value == "International" ){
                        $(".single_add_to_cart_button").hide();
                    }else{
                        $(".single_add_to_cart_button").show(); 
                    }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'load_scripts', 10, 1 );
```

And the HTML code which shows the vendor information is:

```
<a class="by-vendor-name-link" style="display: block;" href="picflick.co.za/vendor/ronks-michael/">Sold By Ronks Michael</a>
```

Unless you know the specific variable of a **WooCommerce Marketplace Vendor** (could be optimal)

Please can someone assist with simple steps to inserting the AND portion of the IF statement to include where its a specific vendor

Much appreciated!

Comment: it misses the html code with the different selection possible..

Comment: @Frenchy I dont understand what you mean. Please explain better, or supply to code to assist. Thnx

Comment: You speak about some dropdown list i dont see that in your sample?